# Sufficient, minimal and correct estimator

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $X$ a random variable with density
$$f(x)=\lambda\theta^\lambda x^{-(\lambda+1)},$$
with $x\geq \theta$, $\lambda>0$ and $\theta>0$.

Let $S=\min\{X_1,\cdots, X_n\}$.

I have the following two questions:

1. Is $S$ a sufficient and minimal estimator of the parameter $\theta$?
2. Is $S$ a unbiased estimator?

I can prove that $S$ is sufficient and that $S$ is the estimator that comes from the maximum likelihood method. I don't know how to prove if $S$ is sufficient or correct.

I also found the distribution of $S$ that, if I am correct, is
$P(S\leq x)=\Big(1-\frac{\theta^\lambda}{x^\lambda}\Big)^n$.

Comment: What is a 'correct' estimator?

Comment: An unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 1):

If $X \ge \theta$, then $\Pr[X < \theta] = 0$, and similarly, $S = \min\{X_1, \ldots, X_n\}$ implies $S \ge \theta$ and $\Pr[S < \theta] = 0$.  Moreover, $\Pr[S > \theta] > 0$:  why?  What does this tell you about $\operatorname{E}[S]$?

As for minimal sufficiency, use the property that $S$ is minimal sufficient if $$\frac{f_\theta(\boldsymbol x)}{f_\theta(\boldsymbol y)}$$ is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $S(\boldsymbol x) = S(\boldsymbol y)$ for samples $\boldsymbol x$ and $\boldsymbol y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree that $P(S<\theta)=0$ and I thing that $P(S>\theta)=(P(X>\theta))^n=1$. Therefore $E(S)>\theta$ and consequently the estimator $S$ is not unbiased. Is this correct?

Comment: If this is correct I have a question.  $S$ is the estimator that I find also using the maximum likelihood method. Is not true that the maximum likelihood estimators are unbiased?

Comment: About the minimality I can conclude that $S$ is sufficient but not minimal because that ratio in my case is always independent if $\theta$. Is this correct? Can I ask the name of this criteria for the minimality?

Comment: @user268193 $S$ is biased as you correctly deduced in your first comment.  This also illustrates that maximum likelihood estimators are not always unbiased.  As another example, the MLE for the variance of a normal distribution with known mean $\mu$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma^2$, hence the existence of Bessel's correction.

Comment: @user268193 As for minimality, you need to remember that the density is actually $$f_\theta(x \mid \lambda) = \lambda \theta^\lambda x^{-(\lambda+1)} \color{red}{\mathbb 1 (x \ge \theta)}.$$  Thus the joint density for a sample has a dependence of $\theta$ on the sample $\boldsymbol x$ and you cannot ignore it when you compute the quotient.  But because this dependence is reducible to an equivalent statement about the sufficient statistic $S$, it becomes clear that minimality is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks again. How it is called this criteria for minimality?